# Watch rangeSlider values changes with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, uislider

I have a jQuery slider implemented through a directive in AngularJS, which looks something like this:

**html**

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div slider></div>
</div>
```

**directive**

```
myApp.directive('slider', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            //slider settings, .noUiSlider is the method to initialize the slider
            elem.noUiSlider({
                range: [0,1440],
                start: [690,750],
                step: 30,
                connect: true
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This succesfully implements the slider, but calling the method **val()** on elem (my slider) only works once, right when the slider is implemented. I know I need to use some form of **$watch** but I don't know how to do it without the directive itself having an attribute (and then accessing it via **attrs**), which is doesn't.

Essentially, I want to watch for changes to elem.val(), and print off the values when they change - not sure how to go about doing that.

Note: This code is all within an ng-switch, which I'm hoping isn't making my life much, much worse.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to print out the value, you could just handle its `change` event:

```
myApp.directive('slider', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            //slider settings, .noUiSlider is the method to initialize the slider
            elem.noUiSlider({
                range: [0,1440],
                start: [690,750],
                step: 30,
                connect: true
            }).change(function(){
                 //log your value here
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When we work with angular, we usually need to bind the value to a property of the model to conform to angular data-binding mechanism. To do that, you need `ng-model`:

```
myApp.directive('slider', function() {
        return {
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs,ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel) return;
                //slider settings, .noUiSlider is the method to initialize the slider
                elem.noUiSlider({
                    range: [0,1440],
                    start: [690,750],
                    step: 30,
                    connect: true
                }).change(function(){
                     scope.$apply(function () {
                        // update the underlying model's property when slider changes
                         ngModel.$setViewValue(elem.val());
                      });
                });
                ngModel.$render = function() {
                   //update the slider when the underlying model changes.
                   elem.val(ngModel.$viewValue || []);
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

Your html:

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div slider ng-model="sliderValue"></div>
</div>
```

This will bind the slider to a model property named `sliderValue`, you could $watch this property for changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML

```
<input type="text" slider options="options">
```

after that just write following in your controller.

```
$scope.options = {       
             from: 2011,
             to: 2015,
             step: 1,
             dimension: " Year"
         };
```

Comment: in above code.. values will be displayed at drag event without any extra code.. it works fine for me